# How to change line type in legend in ggplot in R

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2

I have an issue with the "ggplot2"-package, where I cannot get the linetypes in the legend.
[image]
The legnd only shows the color  of each line, but not the specific type.

My code looks like:

```
ggplot(data = vStdDevHours, aes(x=Hours)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Yearly_DA, colour = "Yearly_DA")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Winter_DA, colour = "Winter_DA")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Spring_DA, colour = "Spring_DA")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Summer_DA, colour = "Summer_DA")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Fall_DA, colour = "Fall_DA")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Yearly_RT, colour = "Yearly_RT", linetype = "Yearly_RT")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Winter_RT, colour = "Winter_RT", linetype = "Winter_RT")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Spring_RT, colour = "Spring_RT", linetype = "Spring_RT")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Summer_RT, colour = "Summer_RT", linetype = "Summer_RT")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Fall_RT, colour = "Fall_RT", linetype = "Fall_RT")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 130, 10), limits=c(0, 130)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 24, 1)) +
  ggtitle("Yearly and Seaonal Standard Deviation of Real-Time Prices") +
  ylab("Price") +
  xlab("Hours") +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "Std. Dev.", values = c("Winter_DA" = "solid", "Winter_RT" = "dashed", "Fall_DA" = "solid", "Fall_RT" = "dashed", "Summer_DA" = "solid", 
                                                       "Summer_RT" = "dashed", "Spring_DA" = "solid", "Spring_RT" = "dashed", "Yearly_DA" = "solid", "Yearly_RT" = "dashed"))  +
  scale_colour_manual(name ="Std. Dev.", values = c("Winter_DA" = "darkred", "Winter_RT" = "darkred", "Fall_DA" = "steelblue", "Fall_RT" = "steelblue", 
                                                      "Summer_DA" = "forestgreen", "Summer_RT" = "forestgreen", "Spring_DA" = "purple", "Spring_RT" = "purple", 
                                                      "Yearly_DA" = "black", "Yearly_RT" = "black")) + 
  theme_bw() + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

I know that it is related to `scale_linetype_manual`, but all the workarounds I have tried have been unsuccessful.

Hopefully some ggplot wizard can help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
ggplot(data = vStdDevHours, aes(x=Hours)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Yearly_DA, colour = "Yearly_DA", linetype = "Yearly_DA")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Winter_DA, colour = "Winter_DA", linetype = "Winter_DA")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Spring_DA, colour = "Spring_DA", linetype = "Spring_DA")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Summer_DA, colour = "Summer_DA", linetype = "Summer_DA")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Fall_DA, colour = "Fall_DA", linetype = "Fall_DA")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Yearly_RT, colour = "Yearly_RT", linetype = "Yearly_RT")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Winter_RT, colour = "Winter_RT", linetype = "Winter_RT")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Spring_RT, colour = "Spring_RT", linetype = "Spring_RT")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Summer_RT, colour = "Summer_RT", linetype = "Summer_RT")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Fall_RT, colour = "Fall_RT", linetype = "Fall_RT")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 130, 10), limits=c(0, 130)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 24, 1)) +
  ggtitle("Yearly and Seaonal Standard Deviation of Real-Time Prices") +
  ylab("Price") +
  xlab("Hours") +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "Std. Dev.", values = c("Winter_DA" = "solid", "Winter_RT" = "dashed", "Fall_DA" = "solid", "Fall_RT" = "dashed", "Summer_DA" = "solid", "Summer_RT" = "dashed",
                                                      "Spring_DA" = "solid", "Spring_RT" = "dashed", "Yearly_DA" = "solid", "Yearly_RT" = "dashed"))  +
  scale_colour_manual(name ="Std. Dev.", values = c("Winter_DA" = "darkred", "Winter_RT" = "darkred", "Fall_DA" = "steelblue", "Fall_RT" = "steelblue", 
                                                      "Summer_DA" = "forestgreen", "Summer_RT" = "forestgreen", "Spring_DA" = "purple", "Spring_RT" = "purple", 
                                                      "Yearly_DA" = "black", "Yearly_RT" = "black")) + 
  theme_bw() + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: Great that you solved your own problem! Could you please identify or highlight the change you made to your code, so if someone else has a similar problem they can try your solution. Thanks!

Comment: I strongly recommend reshaping the data long with `pivot_longer()` so you then can call `geom_line()` only once